# Drying a pot of fresh soil vs drying a pot of soil with bugs

Tags: soil, insects, outdoor

I was trying to dry a fresh pot of soil that I bought from a local store and a pot soil that had been exposed with bugs in it (ants/ flies/creepy crawlies). After about 3 weeks, the pot of fresh soil had completely harden while the other pot with bugs are still moist. Trying to get some opinions here if a garden with such biodiversity (ants/flies/creepy crawlies/visited by lizards) are better for plants or one that is kind of sterile? Are they considered pest or good for plants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, garden with more biodiversity are far better. There will be some bad bugs, but in general other bugs will help to keep garden in equilibrium. It is not always feasible, but it helps.

Also by having varieties of plants help. On monoculture, the diseases spread much easier (many diseases requires a species or genus).

But pots are different. On pots, it is better not to use soil from garden.